# Node.js - how to extract specific column in csv

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to extract specific column in CSV file and create an output file as `index.conf`. In this case I need to extract column under `Service Manager` and `System Owner` and have them as an output file as `index.conf`. Anyone can help?

Image of my CSV:
[image: csv]

```
Client|*Description|Environment|LifeCycle|Service Manager|System Owner|
xxxxxx| xxxxxx     |Production |Active   |Mark Wright    |David harvey| 
xxxxxx| xxxxxx     |Production |Active   |John Stone     |
```

I'm not a developer but just taking over some part of the job scope including maintaining a web site.

Comment: This is not a code writing service. The site is here to help developers with specific problems they are trying to address in their code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **csv** npm package for this. It helps to generate, parse, transform and stringify CSV data. It is a widely used npm package.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) library to convert csv to JSON format.

   npm i --save csvtojson
2. Using JSON parsed from the above step, you can create .conf file as per your requirements.

Refer to following code snippet for the implementation.

> In the following program, I'm considering only the first record of csv. You can write your own logic as per your requirements.

**index.js**

```
// import csvtojson package
const csvtojson = require('csvtojson');
// import fs pacakge to write .conf file
const fs = require('fs')

/**
 * read csv file and save .conf file
 * @param {*} filePath path to the csv file
 */
async function readCSVAndSaveConf(filePath){
    // read csv file on the given path and get csv as json
    const parsedCSV = await readCSV(filePath);
    // save conf as per first record of csv. ** you can write your own logic
    saveConf(parsedCSV[0])
}

/**
 * read csv on given path
 * @param {*} filePath path to csv file
 */
function readCSV(filePath){
return csvtojson({ delimiter: '|' }).fromFile(filePath); 
}

/**
 * save conf file as per json
 * @param {*} jsonConfig 
 */
function saveConf(jsonConfig){
    // create .conf content
    const conf=`# This is conf file
    ServiceManager=${jsonConfig['Service Manager']}
    ServiceOwner=${jsonConfig['System Owner']}`
    // save .conf to the file
    fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/index.conf', conf);
}

// path to csv
const filePath="./input.csv"

// read csv and save conf
readCSVAndSaveConf(filePath)
.then(()=>console.log("completed"))
.catch(err=>console.error(err))
```

**input.csv**

```
Client|*Description|Environment|LifeCycle|Service Manager|System Owner|
xxxxxx| xxxxxx     |Production |Active   |Mark Wright    |David harvey| 
xxxxxx| xxxxxx     |Production |Active   |John Stone     |
```

**index.conf**

```
ServiceManager=Mark Wright
ServiceOwner=David harvey
```